# Automator scripts run Java

Tags: macos, automator, macos-sierra

I need to use Briss, a .jar program, cut the PDF files in order to be display properly on e-ink readers. The basic step is run briss.jar then select open the chose your PDF file. I need automator to do this sequence of actions for me. I open automator, chose new->service->Service receives selected ->PDF->in finder.

Then I drag the briss.jar file into the workflow. and save as BrissPDF

I do see the BrissPDF when I right click a PDF file. But it does not run at all...... I am guessing I didn't pass the PDF file as an input of the briss.jar. Anyone could help?
THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open briss through bash.

First, add the Path variable. Second, add "Run Shell Script", choose to pass input as arguments, and write `java -jar ~/Applications/briss-0.9/briss-0.9.jar "$1"`, or wherever your briss.jar file is . The `$1` part is replaced with the PDF file path, and is passed as an argument to briss.

[Here's a automator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQkHl.png).